# c# newbie: this code is not working like I expected ... why?

Tags: c#

Trying to learn more about less common constructs in C#, I ran into this code sample on codingsight.com:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClassB b = new MyClassB();
            MyClassA a = b;
            a.abc();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class MyClassA
    {
        public MyClassA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("constructor A");
        }

        public void abc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }

    class MyClassB : MyClassA
    {
        public MyClassB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("constructor B");
        }

        public void abc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }
}
```

The challenge is to predict the output. Running the code in a console there appears:

```
constructor A
constructor B
A
```

I had bet my last cent that the 3rd line of the output would be "B", or an "unitialized variable" error, but in fact it is "A". Why?

Comment: Why is it unexpected? The computer is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: You would have to mark MyClassA.abc as `virtual` and MyClassB.abc as `override` to get the output as "B". Basically you'd have to explicitly tell the compiler that MyClassB.abc *replaces* the version from MyClassA.

Comment: What the computer did is "something", but clearly not what the intention of the code was. Obviously the code sample was created to demonstrate some weird behaviour of the "=" operator when used with objects. The fix which meets the objective best is to make use of the .clone() interface.

Comment: Okay, sounds like you know better than me, and better than the compiler. ;) You say "clearly" but that's not "clear" to me at all. Since I read C#, as does your computer, not "whatever other programming language you had in your personal head" ;) Usually one would not expect to magically get `B` behaviour from an `A` context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why?

Because it's a concept of the .NET language called [hiding through inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#hiding-through-inheritance). It's defined that way and there's no reasoning given by Microsoft why it was done that way. They could have chosen any other behavior as well, but they didn't.

In the comments you say:

> What the computer did is "something", but clearly not what the intention of the code was.

Actually, we don't know what the intention was. We would need to ask the author of that code snippet. I would say it was intended the way it is, because it is a great question to see whether or not someone has understood the principles of inheritance.

In the title, you mention that there is a warning - and that warning is exactly a warning to the author that he didn't express his intention well enough. Or it's a warning to you as a reader that the writer has not expressed his intention well enough.

The warning is

> warning CS0108: 'MyClassB.abc()' hides inherited member 'MyClassA.abc()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

That warning also tells us that the author should have used the `new` keyword on `MyClassB.abc()` to definitely tell readers that he's using "hiding through inheritance" explicitly.

Now, what's the alternative? If you want to have inheritance as expected by you, `MyClassA.abc()` needs to be marked as `virtual`.

This change alone, hoewever, does not fix the inheritance as expected by you. There's another compiler warning

> warning CS0114: 'MyClassB.abc()' hides inherited member 'MyClassA.abc()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

which clearly states that `MyClassB.abc()` also needs to be marked as `override`.

It seems you're most confused about the statement

> ```
> MyClassA a = b;
> ```

That statement is equivalent to

```
MyClassA a = (MyClassA) b;
```

but the cast is redundant because of [implicit reference conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-reference-conversions):

> The implicit reference conversions are:
>
> [...]
>
> From any class_type `S` to any class_type `T`, provided `S` is derived from `T`.

(where S is MyClassB and T is MyClassA)

Comment: maybe this makes things clearer: see https://codingsight.com/tricky-questions-about-c-sharp/, question #4.

Comment: I removed the text about the warning, because I have resolved that part myself. Unfortunately I was out of the 5 minutes limit to correct the question title as well. Actually the code sample tests knowledge of 3 facettes of OOP:

- does calling a constructor of a inherited object call the constructor of the parent object (yes, it does). there are other OOP implementations which require you use statements like inherited; to accomplish this. the part I am struggling with is the exact behaviour of the "=" operator when used with objects. It doesn't work like with variables.

Comment: As the author of a question on SO, you can edit your question without any time limit. Only comments have a 5 minute limit.

Comment: @Nimral: I added about implicit reference conversion

Comment: this is what I was looking for! Now it makes sense to me what the output of the program was. Just to check whether I got all this right: the warning about using "new" didn't have anything to do with the problem? It flagged a separate error (unclear inheritance). Other OOP implementations wouldn't throw a warning, they'd draw the conclusion that abc in MyObjectB is intended to overwrite the method with the same name of myObjectA from it's sheer existence, without any warning. Why should anyone overwrite a method, and then not make use of it?

Comment: @Nimral: There is no error in the original code at all. It compiles and executes as defined by the language. This is no misuse of "undefined behavior" or similar like there is in C++. AFAIK, Python wouldn't complain about inheritance. C++ has a [virtual keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) since ever. Unclear inheritance seems to be an issue as well, since they have introduced the [override keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override).